# Support function of a set: when we can replace the supremum with the maximum?

Tags: general-topology, functions, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a set $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ (not necessarily closed and/or convex). Let $k:=(k_1,...,k_i,...,k_d)$ be a generic element of $K$.

Consider the function $h_K:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
h_K(u):=\sup_{k\in K} \sum_{i=1}^d k_iu_i
$$
with $u:=(u_1,...,u_i,...,u_d)\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Under which sufficient conditions on $K$ $\sup_{k\in K} \sum_{i=1}^d k_iu_i=\max_{k\in K} \sum_{i=1}^d k_iu_i$?

Comment: Do you think there is a simple answer on this question?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Just one set of sufficient conditions would be enough.

Comment: One sufficient condition is that $K$ is compact.